# Save/Retrieve User drawing Core Graphics &swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

Hey guys so I'm working on an app using the apple pencil, and there aren't many resources around on this so hopefully someone here can help.

What i'm my app does is it let's the user draw an image using the apple pencil, a UIImage view and core graphics to create the context and such. I now want to be able to save what the user has drawn ideally using NSData, however since it's being saved as a PNG how would I be able to load that saved file and get it on the UIImage screen again?

Thanks!

Here's my Core Graphics code :

```
let π = CGFloat(M_PI)

class NoteCanvasView: UIImageView {

private var defaultLineWidth:CGFloat = 1

private var drawColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Draw previous image into context
    image?.drawInRect(bounds)

    drawStroke(context, touch: touch)

    // Update image
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

private func drawStroke(context: CGContext?, touch: UITouch) {
    let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInView(self)
    let location = touch.locationInView(self)

    // Calculate line width for drawing stroke
    let lineWidth = lineWidthForDrawing(context, touch: touch)

    // Set color
    drawColor.setStroke()

    // Configure line
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Round)


    // Set up the points
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, previousLocation.x, previousLocation.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, location.x, location.y)
    // Draw the stroke
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

}

private func lineWidthForDrawing(context: CGContext?, touch: UITouch) -> CGFloat {

    var lineWidth = defaultLineWidth

    return lineWidth
}
func saveNote(){
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setObject(data, forKey: "test123")
    userDefaults.synchronize()

}
func retrieveNote(){
    if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("test123"),let image = UIImage(data: data){

    }

}

func setStrokeColor(color: UIColor){
    drawColor = color
}
func setStrokeWidth(size: CGFloat){
    defaultLineWidth = size
}

func clearCanvas(animated animated: Bool) {
    if animated {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { finished in
                self.alpha = 1
                self.image = nil
        })
    } else {
        image = nil
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can got image back from data like,

```
 UIImage(data:imageData,scale:1.0)
```

take `UIImage` reference and get image like this and you can display that image on your `imageview`

hope this will help :)

Comment: By imageview do you mean my UIImageView?? Because when i try making it the background image it doesnt show up

Comment: Wow it worked out! The only reason I was asking and was hesitant was because when I tried setting an image in the storyboard to my UIImageView it would show up in the editor but when I ran it, it wouldn't. Appreciate the help!

Comment: If you feel that it is helpful then accept answer so other people with similar issue can use it. :)

Comment: Sorry new to stack overflow! I hit the checkmark and it's green so i'm assuming that it :) Thank you once again!

Answer (score -1):

You could save it and retrieve as NSData. I'm still not sure whats the best way to handle sketches, I would think NSData as well.  Will try it and let you know.